# Integration of a function in R

Tags: r, integrate

I would like to integrate a function with respect to `x`,

```
FUN1 <- function(x, alpha, beta){
 x * alpha - beta
}

FUN2 <- function(alpha beta){
  integrate(FUN1(x, alpha,beta）, 0,1）
}
```

But it does not work.

I also tried

```
FUN2 <- function(alpha beta){
  integrate(FUN1, 0,1）
}
```

It does not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, and also read the docs,

```
f1 = function(x, a, b) x * a - b

f2 = function(a, b) integrate(f1, 0, 1, a, b) # a and b are passed to f1 through ...

f2(3, 4)
```